# df.replace doesn't replace ]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I'm trying to remove the `[` and `]` from. It looks like this:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B'],
         'col2': ['[1, 5, 30]', '[1, 10, 20]']})
```

I can remove the `[` just fine using:

```
dftest = dftest.replace({'\[':''}, regex = True)
```

However, when I try the same thing for `]`, none are removed:

```
dftest = dftest.replace({'\]':''}, regex = True)
```

How can I remove that final `]`? Why does it not work the same as `[`? Desired output:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B'],
         'col2': ['1, 5, 30', '1, 10, 20']})
```

Running this exact thing in a new cell in Jupyter Lab returns a dataframe with no changes:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B'],
         'col2': ['[1, 5, 30]', '[1, 10, 20]']})
dftest = dftest.replace({'\]':''}, regex = True)
```

However, running this *does* replace `[`:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B'],
         'col2': ['[1, 5, 30]', '[1, 10, 20]']})
dftest = dftest.replace({'\]':''}, regex = True)
```

Maybe it's a problem with my Jupyter Lab?? Here is a screenshot of those two code segments with their output just in case that helps (and to prove something strange is going on with my notebook, I guess):

[image]

Comment: It is work for me

Comment: Same. Cannot reproduce

Comment: This is bizarre. I updated my question to include my exact setup - running Jupyter Lab, that exact segment of code does not drop the `]` for me.

Comment: You've changed the question now. Now you're suggesting that _none_ of the `replace` operations are working. Which situation is it? Also, if you're not already doing, make sure you copy/paste the code directly from Jupyter and change none of the names, just indentation if you need to. My bet is on a typo on a name.

Comment: Edited to clarify. I can drop the `[`, but not the `]` using the exact same method. I am copying/pasting directly from my notebook cell.

Comment: `dftest = dftest.replace({'[\]\[]':''}, regex = True)` works for me. Cannot reproduce. Can you clarify: a) python version,  b) `pd.__version__` ?

Comment: That modification works for me! If it's still relevant, I'm running python 3.7 and pandas 0.24.1

Answer (score 0):

there is another solution, use `literal_eval` from `ast` library

**code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

dftest = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B'],
                       'col2': ['[1, 5, 30]', '[1, 10, 20]']})
print(dftest)
# print(dftest.col2.dtype)
D = dftest.at[0, 'col2']
print(type(D))  # taking particular cell
dftest['col2'] = dftest['col2'].apply(literal_eval)
D = dftest.at[0, 'col2']  # taking particular cell
print(type(D))
```

**output:**

```
  col1         col2
0    A   [1, 5, 30]
1    B  [1, 10, 20]
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
```

**for example:**

```
from ast import literal_eval
print(literal_eval('[1, 5, 30]'))
print(type('[1, 5, 30]'))
print(type(literal_eval('[1, 5, 30]')))
```

**output:**

```
[1, 5, 30]
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
```